# WIndows 11 read only folders

Tags: windows

I am having an issue whereby all the folders on my C drive are in read only mode

I am logged in with an administrator account

When I try to uncheck the read only attribute box in windows explorer for any folder it executes the changes, however immediately the folder reverts to being read only

I have check in powershell if Controlled Folder Access is disabled, got a response of 0

Get-MpPreference | Select-Object -ExpandProperty EnableControlledFolderAccess

Windows 11 is fully up to date with all updates and the clock is set correctly

any ideas why windows is forcing all folders into read only mode?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What folders ?   If the other USERS folder, what you describe is how native Windows works.  You would need to permit them to whatever USER needs them. If ALL folder, something is wrong with your system.

Comment: yes i am aware there is something wrong with my system, all folders

Comment: Back up your documents, then Repair Install or Reinstall Windows and restore your backup.

Comment: Most users are confused by the "read-only" checkbox.  Can you provide a screenshot?

Comment: "The Read-only and System attributes is only used by Windows Explorer to determine whether the folder is a special folder" - [You cannot view or change the Read-only or the System attributes of folders in Windows Server 2003, in Windows XP, in Windows Vista or in Windows 7](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/you-cannot-view-or-change-the-read-only-or-the-system-attributes-of-folders-in-windows-server-2003-in-windows-xp-in-windows-vista-or-in-windows-7-55bd5ec5-d19e-6173-0df1-8f5b49247165). So you can ignore that checkbox.

Comment: Check the SMART data of your disk for errors. A disk with too many errors will set itself into read-only mode.